# Angular 2 - sanitizing HTML

Tags: angular, sanitization

I desperate to the sanitize of angular :( "WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content".

All I want is to display a div thats finished in json in angular2 within a ngfor loop. With the doku of angular, I'm unfortunately overwhelmed as a beginner and I cant find examples for a loop.

Here part of template-html - I tried to mask it with the innerHTML:

```html
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" *ngFor="let item of _Interface; let i = index">
    <div [innerHTML]="item.timeline"></div>
```

But Angular show me only the text of the div.

The data of json / timeline element contains a div like this

```html
 "timeline": "<div class=\"timeline\"><span style = \"width: 10%; height: 3px; background - color:#376635; display:inline-block;\" ></ span >< span style=\"width:90%; height:3px; background-color:#d9d9d4; display:inline-block;\" ></span></div>",
```

Comment: what "text of the div" are you talking about?

Comment: My timeline-json element contains content like this "<div class=\"timeline\"><span style = \"width: 10%; height: 3px; background - color:#376635; display:inline-block;\" ></ span >< span style=\"width:90%; height:3px; background-color:#d9d9d4; display:inline-block;\" ></span></div>"